# How to get SpringSecurity/Grails to play nicely with a Load Balancer that is terminating SSL

Tags: spring, tomcat, grails, spring-security, amazon-elb

We have a Grails app on Tomcat deployed behind a Load Balancer that is terminating SSL (the load balancer then communicates with tomcat instances on port 8080).  We have configured SpringSecurity to require a secure channel on all resources, pay attention to the headers from the load balancer, to force https and to map the ports from the load balancer:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.forceHttps = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**': 'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL'
]
```

Most of this is working correctly - redirects from within Grails are using the https protocol as expected, as well as most ajax requests.

There are some ajax requests however that are *not* working correctly.  They all relate to results of interacting with j_spring_security* endpoints like j_spring_security_check.  For example, if a user tries to login via ajax, we get this error in the browser (this is the redirect that the successful login initiates):

```
 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.servernamehere.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but 
 requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.servernamehere.com/login/ajaxSuccess'.
 This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

The same problem happens upon unsuccessful authentication:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.servernamehere.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested 
an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.servernamehere.com/login/authfail?ajax=true'. 
This request has been blocked; the content must be served over https.
```

How can we configure spring security to understand that all redirects coming out of authentication events need to be https?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to fix this issue by creating a custom Redirect strategy (implement org.springframework.security.web.RedirectStrategy) and replacing the default redirect strategy bean with our custom one.  The custom redirect strategy examines the headers passed in by the load balancer and makes sure that the response is redirected to the appropriate protocol

Comment: Mike, having the same problem here, can you post an example of what you did? thanks!

Comment: I have run into the exact same problem. Can you post an example?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup where I set in my Grails app secureChanel headers like this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.useHeaderCheckChannelSecurity = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.secureHeaderValue = 'http'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderName = 'X-Forwarded-Proto'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.insecureHeaderValue = 'https'
```

There was a bug in both versions (2.x, 3.x) of Grails spring security plugin https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/issues/395 however it has been fixed already....